# How to output rich text (html) field content when outputting to PDF using Apache FOP

Tags: xpages, apache-fop

I am trying to generate a PDF file using an xAgent and Apache FOP as suggested by Stephen Wissel here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8TNLTV. Most of the process is working fine, the xAgent is called, creates the XML from my document and passes it through the transform to output a PDF. I am just stuck on how to handle the rich text fields. The fields contain user-generated content (created in an xPage) and so contain HTML fragments. Has anyone come up with a good way to output rich text fields along with other content to a PDF?

Rich

Comment: I haven't worked directly with xAgent and Apache FOP, but from when I used a FOP product to generate PDFs, I needed to pipe the HTML through XSL to convert the formatting to tags the FOP understood.
'<xsl:template match="h1">
 <para>
  <xsl:attribute name="font-size">24pt</xsl:attribute>
   <emphasis role="bold">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </emphasis>
  </para>
</xsl:template>'

edit: trying to figure out code formatting

Comment: If you get this working please post on OpenNTF as a snippet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RichText is a [insert something unprintable]. There are a number of considerations:

- Do you require RichText in its full client beauty (tabbed tables, OLE, sections, hovers etc.)?
- Is the HTML representation of RichText good enough (the one when you look at it through a browser - eventually **enriched** by [AppsFidelity](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/AppsFidelity))?

In the former case your probably only avenue is to grab the DXL representation and try to convert that one - I played with that, it seems to be feasible but a long and painful road.

In the later case, you first get hands on the HTML representation. That can be done using the [?OpenField](http://www.iminstant.com/iminstant/iminstant.nsf/d6plinks/ctyr-7h6s6r) command or the [code snipped by Mark](http://linqed.eu/2014/07/11/getting-html-from-any-richtext-item/).

Now you have HTML, you might want to cleanup using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and then convert that one to XSL:FO. Some guidance can be found here:

- A [Developerworks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslfo2app/) outlining conversion options, including a sample style sheet
- A [wiki article](http://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-fop/HowTo/HtmlToPdf) in the FOP Wiki, pointing to a style sheet and a tool

Unfortunately not a copy/paste solution, but could be doable. Let us know how it goes, the topic seems of **general interest** for XPages and Domino.

**Update**
To successfully transform HTML you need to convert it into xHTML. This roughly works like this:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document hDoc = Jsoup.parse(source);
String cleanHTML = hDoc.body().html();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(cleanHTML));
DocumentBuilder docb = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document d = docb.parse(source);
return d;
```

For an XSLT transformation you don't need to go to a full document first, a `InputSource` will do just nicely.

Along these lines...

```
   /* Stylesheet most likely would come from a getResourceAsStream */
   public String getFO(String rawHTML, InputStream styleStream) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document hDoc = Jsoup.parse(rawHTML);
        String cleanHTML = hDoc.body().html();
        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(cleanHTML));
        StreamSource style = new StreamSource(styleStream);
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(style);
        StreamResult xResult = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, xResult);
        String result = xResult.getWriter().toString();
        return result;
   }
```

Of course you need to add error handling etc. Let us know how it goes

Comment: I do only need the html representation as it is all created on an xpage and is stored as MIME/Html. I have retrieved the HTML fragment from the field as a string and now I guess I just need to transform it to a DOM tree.    jTidy does offer the possibility of a DOM Document directly but hasn't been updated in a while. jsoup has its own tree that would have to be further transformed. I did see the DeveloperWorks article and have been reviewing/comparing  that with the Antenna House style sheet. Both of those seem to expect a full HTML document and set up the pages and everything.

Comment: I successfully used jsoup to cleanup HTML into xhtml - that is what you need. Once it is valid XML the standard Java XML Dom methods will work just nicely. I'll dig into the box of 'once-written-code' when next to my PC and see if I can find the sample

Comment: I see that soup also has a helper class that will return a w3c dom document, so I should be able to use that to merge in with my other content before passing it to the transform. This is what I will be trying and I will report back on my success.

Answer (score 1):

Your users create and fill the RichText fields in XPages with CKEditor only. That is a good precondition for converting to pdf. Your Richtext fields are in HTML format.

Use the following steps:

1. Convert your HTML to XHTML. [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/download.html) is a good tool for this. XHTML has a stronger syntax than HTML and is easier to convert to FOP this way.
2. Integrate AntennaHouse's [xhtml2fo.xsl](http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/sample-xsl-xhtml2fo/xhtml2fo.xsl) into your XSL. There is an [adapted extended version](https://github.com/jeffrafter/xhtml2fo) available which works pretty well.

Comment: Fop does support inline images - so some additional magic in the HTML preprocessing with JTidy or jsoup might be required